# how to prevent image from flickering on uri reload in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I have an image src coming as a socket response. It reloads multiple times in a second, whenever it changes the image flickers. Is there any way I can get rid of this unwanted flickering whenever a new source is being loaded.

Comment: Just use 2 Images, set one invisible and flip, after the image has loaded.

Comment: Thanks Keith, but I am getting response from the socket and setting it in a state as a result component rerenders again. It is already slowing down the screen and If I manage another new state, it will hang it so bad. Is there anything you can help me how can I set it without using any state, so that I can use 2 images one for fliping and one set as invisible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-native-fast-image for uri image. it very good.

Comment: Hi @NhuyenManhHoan, could you please add more detail to your answer? If you're unsure take a look at the help center on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I have used react-native-fast-image as well, it also flashes the image whenever a new src is loaded into it even if I set high priority.